# bug in clojure URL shortener during auto-generation of IDs

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I came across a snippet of code in the Clojure Programming and it was buggy. I'm a newbie to Clojure and cant figure out where the bug is in the code.

```
(ns ring-tutorial.core
  (:require [compojure.handler :as ch]
        [compojure.core :refer [GET PUT POST defroutes]]
        [compojure.route :as cr]
        [ring.util.response :as response]))

(def ^:private counter (atom 0))
(def ^:private mappings (ref {}))

(defn url-for
[id]
(@mappings id))

(defn shorten!
 "Stores the given URL under a new unique identifier and returns it as a string."
 ([url]
 (let [id (swap! counter inc)
       id (Long/toString id 36)] ;;convert to base 36 string
   (or (shorten! url id)
       (recur url))))
([url id] ;;url is provided with an id.
 (dosync
  (when-not (@mappings id)
    (alter mappings assoc id url)
    id))))

(defn retain
 [& [url id :as args]]
(if-let [id (apply shorten! args)]
{:status 201
  :headers {"Location" id}
 :body (list "URL " url " assigned the short identifier " id " \n")}
{:status 409 :body (format "Short URL %s is already taken \n " id)}))

(defn redirect
 [id]
(if-let [url (url-for id)]
(ring.util.response/redirect url) ;;Appropriately redirect the URL based on ethe ID.
{:status 404 :body (str "No such short URL: \n" id)})) ;;Return a 404 if no URL for the particular ID found.

(defroutes app*
 (GET "/" request "Hello World!")
 (PUT "/:id" [id url] (retain url id))
 (POST "/" [url ] (retain url))
 (GET "/:id" [id] (redirect id))
 (GET "/list/" [] (interpose "\n" (keys @mappings)))
 (cr/not-found "Its a 404!\n"))

(def app (ch/api #'app*))
```

When i run $ CURL -X POST 'localhost:8080/?url=http://www.yahoo.com/' 
I get URL has been given identifier 1
when i rerun the command I get 'URL has been given the identifer 2 but it should flag an error saying yahoo.com has identifier 1 already.

this is the bug i can see that its in the shorten! function but havent been able to correct it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `mappings` ref points to a map of shortened ID to long URL. In the `shorten!` function, you need to take a URL and see if there's already an ID assigned to it. Instead, you're generating a new ID every time and looking it up in the map to see if a URL is assigned to it, which will never be the case.

To fix this, you would need to maintain a second mapping, of long URL to shortened ID. Inside the `dosync` block, you would first look up the URL in this new map, and if the URL is not found then generate an ID and add the URL, ID pair to both maps.

Comment: So should i create a new Ref called mappings2 {}. then (@mappings2 url). and have another when-not inside the dosync? something like
(dosync
(when-not (@mappings2 url) something? )

I'm a little confused, some code would really help. :)